# cellForRowAtIndexPath is getting called only once

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I don't know what I am doing wrong but the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of table view is getting called only once.

Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

     NSLog(@"--->%d",[collaboratoresdata count]);

    return [collaboratoresdata count];

}
```

When my `collaboratoresdata` array is filled, then I am calling `[_collaboratortblView reloadData]` to reload the table view.

I am successfully getting `3` in `NSLog(@"--->%d",[collaboratoresdata count]);` but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is getting called only one time.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    // add a placeholder cell while waiting on table data

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    NSLog(@"tableView:%d",[indexPath row]);// i am getting 0 here than after its not calling

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: What is shown on the screen?

Comment: After your NSLog write cell.textLabel.text = @"hi";

Comment: @HotLicks its just showing first element of array.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique it just showing me only one cell although my array has count 3 value.

Comment: Have you set a row height?

Comment: @Wain No, its default one

Comment: can you scroll in your tableView? Maybe you made your cells huge.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch its not about displaying the cell i am NSLoging the ndexpath.row in cellForRowAtIndexPath method and its showing me 0 means this method is calling only ones although i am passing my array count in  numberOfRowsInSection method and my array count is 3

Comment: yes. and since a tableView only calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when it actually displays a cell it is important to know if you can scroll. If a single cell is taller than the whole tableView `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will be called exactly one time.

Comment: Yeah, did you try simply scrolling the display?

Comment: And are you sure that your app didn't hang after fetching the first cell?

Answer (score 0):

check the height of cell i think thats the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
please try to set height of cell manually(custom). So, if problem of cell height then it will be resolved. below method set cell height 30 pixels.

#pragma mark- TableView delegate Methods
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
return 30.0f;
}
```